# Calling karate feature with variable

Tags: cucumber-jvm, karate

In karate you can call feature by sending json/list & map. There are multiple ways I have tried to send the value and use it in the called feature but it throws error

For example:

> Error thrown : path: $, actual: '', expected:
>   '30e093da-c4e3-4ee0-b180-e5d0b4302d9f', reason: not a sub-string

Step:`* call read('Logcheck.feature') {requestId : "#(responseHeaders['request-id'][0])"}`

In the logCheck feature I am trying to get requestId by using `#(requestId)`

Logcheck feature Step

```
* def resultFromServiceLog = utils.getResultFromLog(baseUrl,'#(requestId)','service')
```

---

I have tried another approach where I have assigned it to

```
* def x = {requestId : responseHeaders['request-id'][0]}
* call ('logcheck.feature;) x
```

---

Another approach where I will send the json

`* json req = {requestId : "#(responseHeaders['request-id'][0])"}
* call read('logcheck.feature') req`

Step for logcheck.feature
`* print req
 * def resultFromServiceLog = utils.getResultFromLog(baseUrl,'#(requestId)','service')`

For example:

> Error thrown : com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: 
>   javascript evaluation failed: utils.getResultFromLog(baseUrl,'#> 
>   (requestId)','service'), null

print req output is

> [print] {"requestId": "c996f752-c288-40c7-9398-c913254971e6"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be clear about using embedded expressions, please read the docs again: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

For example this is wrong:

```
* def resultFromServiceLog = utils.getResultFromLog(baseUrl,'#(requestId)','service')
```

Instead:

```
* def resultFromServiceLog = utils.getResultFromLog(baseUrl, requestId, 'service')
```

And this is wrong:

```
 * call ('logcheck.feature') x
```

You probably meant:

```
* call read('logcheck.feature') x
```